# MS Access: Immediate update of related subforms

Tags: ms-access, subform

I have a form (F) with 2 subforms (SF1 and SF2). I also have 3 Oracle tables (T1, T2 and T3). Every (sub)form corresponds to a table:

```
F -> T1
SF1 -> T2
Sf2 -> T3
```

Also, every (sub)form shows a list of rows, depending on some conditions:

```
* F shows all rows of T1.
* SF1 shows rows of T2 based on the row selected in F.
* SF2 shows rows of T3 based on the row selected in SF1.
```

To make it possible:

```
* In SF1: A field of SF1 is linked to the "id" field of F.
* In SF2: A field of SF2 is linked to a special control of F.
```

The special control of F is a textbox that has a special SourceControl property:

```
=[SF1].[Form]![ID]
```

that takes the id of the row selected at SF1.

Ok, now the problem: If the user selects a different row at F, then both the SF1 rows and the SF2 rows are INMEDIATELY updated. But, if the user selects a different row at SF1, then the SF2 rows are NOT INMEDIATELY updated, they are updated perhaps 0.3 or 0.5 seconds after the user changed the selection.

What is the cause of such a different behabior? Is it possible to update rows INMEDIATELY in the second case too?

---

**Update**: Solved: Just call SF2.Requery() at SF1's Form_Current() event, and SF2 content will be updated inmediately when the user changes selection at SF1:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()                  ' at Form__SF1 module

    Dim SF2 As Form
    On Error Resume Next
    Set SF2 = Me.Parent("SF2").Form         ' SF2 is a son of the parent
    If Err <> 0 Then                        ' parent not openned
        Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    SF2.Requery                             ' update SF2 content

End Sub
```

Comment: sounds like it's working properly in both cases just slow for one. How big are the tables? Are they proportionally large? How are the indices set up?

Comment: Is SF2 a subform in F or in SF1?

Comment: Tables are very little since they are still development tables, the have about 5 to 10 rows. I believe that the size is not the reason. Both SF1 and SF2 are subforms of F (SF2 is not a subform of SF1). The strange thing is that, if user changes selection in F, then SF2 (and SF1) is updated inmediately. But, if the user changes selection in SF1, then SF2 is updated after 0.3-0-5 seconds. As I explained at the response to Alan Waage's comment, SF2 depends on the selection at SF1 by using an intermediate textbox at F, that takes the selected value from SF1, and is read by SF2.

Answer (score 1):

Add an after update event to the cell in F1 that means SF1 and SF2 need to update.  In that event call .Requery on SF1 and SF2

Comment: No luck, the event is not fired. I have added a basic sub function (that contains a MsgBox sentence) for the AfterUpdate event of the special control (the textbox). The value of the textbox is changed inmediately when the user selects other row in SF1, but the event doesn't happen (no dialog is shown). Also tried with Change event, same result. Perhaps the events are not launched because the value of the textbox is set by the special SourceControl property ("=[SF1].[Form]![ID]")?

Comment: the textbox linked to SF1 is not where to put the after update check.  "But, if the user selects a different row at SF1"  This is where you need the event call.  Going by the information provided.

Comment: The texbox at form F takes its value from the selection at subform SF1 (with the formula "=[SF1].[Form]![ID]"). Subform SF2 takes the value of the texbox at form F, and shows rows acordingly. There is no VBA code, everything has been designed graphically (in "Design mode"). When the user changes selection at SF1, F's textbox value is updated inmediately, but SF2 is not updated inmediately, it is updated after 0.3-0.5 seconds.

Comment: " When the user changes selection at SF1, F's textbox value "  This is what you have to trigger from. So it would not be an after update event. You will have to go by one of the mouse events.

Comment: I solved it by adding code to the Form_Current event at SF1 (see the "Update" section at the question).